# How to get around urllib2.HTTP when running a python script

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to run a python script in Windows 7 in the command prompt, however I keep receiving this error every time I try to run it.

```
File "inb4404.py", line 73
  except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
                          ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I located the directory containing the python script using 'cd' and also have Python in my PATH. Then I wrote 'python inb4404.py' and received that error.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're trying to run a Python 2 script in Python 3.  Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you are using is written for Python 2 but you are running it using Python 3.

Depending on what your goals are, you have a few options. The simplest would be to run the script using Python 2. You may already have it in the `c:\Python27\python` directory or can install it. See these [Window tips](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html) for details or download it [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/).

If you want to get more involved, you can manually change the script over to Python 3. This would take some [reading up on the differences](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html#capturing-the-currently-raised-exception) such as the one you encountered with the except `urllib2.HTTPError, err` becoming `except urllib2.HTTPError as err`. The script you are running is small so it may be doable but if it relies on Python 2 only libraries it could get more complex fast. Additional tools and info for converting Python 2 to 3 is available at [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) which provides a tool that identifies issues and can even automatically fix them for you but like most automatic tools, it may not do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.
If you want `err` to be the error object, it should be `except urllib2.HTTPError as err:`